# Python3 PyQt4 Calling function from QPushButton

Tags: python, pyqt4

I try to achieve a very simple thing in PyQT4 (python 3.3) :
Calling a new window from a button.

So far I have a 2nd Class (my second window, empty for now)...:

```
class Window2(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window2, self).__init__()
        self.initUI2()


    def initUI2(self):

        self.vbox2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        self.setLayout(self.vbox2)       
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 200, 120)
        self.setWindowTitle('Image Bits')
        self.show()

    def main2():
        w2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        w2.resize(150, 150)
        w2.move(300, 300)
        w2.setWindowTitle('Window2')
        w2.show()
```

which is called byt this function in my main class:

```
    def FN_OpenWindow2(self):            
        win2 = Window2()
        #Display it
        win2.show()
```

Function which is called by this button in the same class :

```
self.NextButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Next")
self.NextButton.setCheckable(True)
self.NextButton.clicked[bool].connect(self.FN_OpenWindow2)
```

I must not be totally wrong because I have indeed my second window called and opening... a fraction of seconds... I guess only the time the button is "pushed".

So here's my question, how do I  keep a reference to the instance of  class Window2 ? so once called it stay here (and if I hit again the same button I will just destroy/create to refresh, that's my plan).

Hope I am clear enough, apologize if not I am fairly new to Python.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, you just have to keep reference to the new window alive.
E.g. by simply storing it inside your main class:

```
def FN_OpenWindow2(self):            
    self.win2 = Window2()
    #Display it
    self.win2.show()
```

Or, if you could have multiple of those, make it a list:

```
def __init__(self,...):
    # initialize an empty list in you main class' init function
    self.secondaryWindows = []

def FN_OpenWindow2(self):            
    win2 = Window2()
    #Display it
    win2.show()
    # append the window to the list
    self.secondaryWindows.append(win2)
```

Mind though, that the references will remain when you close those widgets again.
So it maybe necessary to add additional logic that clears the references at that point.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very helpful, I wasn't really far from the truth then ! I need to play more with that, the list is very nice I like it (and might be easier/cleaner to clear the reference with): )
Trying that tonight : )